# Media queries is not working on the screen size of 450px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

https://jsfiddle.net/t1etnj5w/1/

i want to make the above demo full responsive the text should be in the center. But when i am trying to add padding-left:10% in the @media screen (max-width:450px) it is not working.
    It has worked above 600px screen.
    Please see the above demo.

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/t1etnj5w/1/
```

Answer (score 1):

because of header position:aboslute and minus margin css it's not shows properly.

```
 header {
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
left: 22%;
z-index: 999;
color: #fff;
/*background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
padding: 60px;
 margin: -200px 0 0 -200px
}
```

Comment: what ever text i add is coming on the video i want the content below the video.Even if i take a separate section it is coming on the video.Its because of the fullscreen video

Comment: header margin:values in minus that's moves all the header content to left side -200px so we can't able to see that padding-left:10%.

Comment: As a good css developer sholud not use margin values in minus.